# Python selenium WebDriverWait waits until the end of page load and not the event I mentioned

Tags: python, selenium

For some reason, while I am trying to wait for an element by any criteria (visibility, presence etc.) It waits until the whole page is loaded and not only the specific element.
The page uses `GTM` if it is related, and that the relevant part in the code :

```
ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'menu-item-15608')))
startLoadReg = time.time()
driver.find_element_by_id("menu-item-15608").click()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
RegTabLoaded = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 45).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "page-title")))
endLoadReg = time.time()
```

Does any one know what might cause it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you get the page in Selenium it first waits untill the Document readiness state becomes complete. See https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-waiting-for-the-navigation-to-complete

So even if you have some "waiters" for specific conditions on specific elements, Selenium will wait while the initial DOM will be built.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected it and it's explains the problem.